# Joining elements of list: Python

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have list given as:

```
x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']
```

How can I use the `''.join()` function to ignore the newline characters and obtain `'abcd'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
''.join(c for c in x if c != '\n')
```

Comment: `''.join(filter('\n'.__ne__,x))`

Comment: @YannVernier, That's almost as fast as just doing the replace afterward. 0.769 vs 0.596

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
''.join(c for c in x if c.isalpha())
```

This way, you can remove `\n`, `\t` and any other special characters

```
>>> x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']
>>> ''.join(c for c in x if c.isalpha())
'abcd'
>>>
```

Comment: Can this be used in Python 2.7?

Comment: This will remove digits and punctuation too.  (That may work just fine for the OP's case, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with filter

```
''.join(filter(lambda a: a != '\n', x))
```

or

```
''.join(filter(lambda a: a.isalpha(), x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join([x.strip() for x in ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simple is not just simple it's much faster too

```
x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']
''.join(x).replace('\n', '')
```

for really long lists, this seems to be a little faster

```
''.join(x).translate(None, '\n')
```

Here are some timings.

```
$ python -m timeit -s"x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']" "''.join(c for c in x if c!='\n')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']" "''.join(c for c in x if c.isalpha())"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.29 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']" "''.join(filter(lambda a: a != '\n', x))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']" "''.join(x).replace('\n','')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.593 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"x = ['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n', '\n', 'd']" "''.join(x).replace('\n','')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.596 usec per loop
```

Comment: Hello. I thought that ``''.join(c for c in x if not(c is '\n'))`` could be faster than ``''.join(c for c in x if c !='\n')``. But it gives ``'a\nb\nc\n\nd'`` as a result, and I don't understand why. Would you se better than me ? I am perplexd

Comment: By the way, there's an error of typing in the first timeit: must be ``for c != '\n'`` not ``for x != '\n'``

Comment: @eyquem, interestingly it's now the same speed as filter+lambda

Comment: @eyquem, strings are immutable, but not all identical strings have to have the same id. Aside, Python lets you say `if c is not '\n'` which is easier to read but has the same problem

Comment: _" not all identical strings have to have the same id"_ I'm surprised by this affirmation, I would like to know more. The problem is that if you run the code ``for c in ['a','\n','b']:`` ``print repr(c),not (c is '\n')`` you get ``a' True``,``'\n' False``, ``'b' True``, however ``repr(''.join(c for c in ['a','\n','b'] if not(c is '\n')))`` gives ``'a\nb'``